# Проверка существует ли пользователь с таким именем Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте, возможно кто-то знаком с проблемой.
база MSSQL Server

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"), 
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "personal_id")}, name = "`user`")
public class User implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 30)
@Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
private String username;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 60)
@Column(length = 60, nullable = false)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Personal personal;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Privilege privilege;

private boolean locked;
```

Контролер

```
@Override
protected void additionalValidation(User user, User oldUser, BindingResult 
bindingResult) {
    if (oldUser == null) {
        if (repository.usernameOccupied(user.getUsername()))            
           bindingResult.rejectValue("username", null, "already exist");
    } else if (!oldUser.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername()) && 
repository.usernameOccupied(user.getUsername()))
        bindingResult.rejectValue("username", null, "already exist");
    }
```

и репозиторий

```
@Query("select count(u.id)>0 from User u where u.username = :username")
boolean usernameOccupied(@Param("username") String username);
```

Ошибка на этой операции `count(u.id)>0` 
буду рад любой подсказке

Comment: Просто `@Query("select count(u.id) from User u where u.username = :username")` и сравнение полученного значения с нулём или единицей уже в программе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так :

```
@Query(select case when count(u.id) > 0 then true else false end from User u where u.username = :username)
boolean usernameOccupied(@Param("username") String username);
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!